# nodejs express 4.0 post json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I am trying to parse the json object sent in the request and echo out the data being sent
Here is my post request

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            name:"Bob"
        }),
        // processData: false, // this is optional
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

Here is how I am trying to access the object parameters

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var router = express.Router();
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use('/api', router);
    app.listen(8010);
    router.post('/addUser', function(req, res){
         console.log(req.body);

    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't `name:"Bob"` be `"name":"Bob"`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need :

```
router.post('/addUser', function(req, res){
   console.log(req.body.name);  
});
```

**EDIT**

After testing it, you also miss these two lines (*or you didn't include them on purpose*) :

```
app.use(router); //You need to register your rooter as a middleware
app.listen(1234); //Your port of choice
```

Comment: I tried using req.body.name. I am testing the client using Postman however my req.body is always empty

Comment: Figured it out. The problem was with the Postman client I was using for testing. It would not send the request properly. Switched to a different client

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the fact that you use the middleware '[body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)'.

What it does is simple, it parses the data and creates a body object as a parameter of your request.

Therefore, the name parameter you're looking for will be found in : req.body.name and not in param

**Quote from the github page :**

> **req.body**
>
> A new body object containing the parsed data is populated on the request object after the middleware.